# Python: How to sort a list of dictionaries by several values?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list at first by a value and then by a second value. Is there an easy way to do this? Here is a small example:

```
A = [{'name':'john','age':45},
     {'name':'andi','age':23},
     {'name':'john','age':22},
     {'name':'paul','age':35},
     {'name':'john','age':21}]
```

This command is for sorting this list by `'name'`:

```
sorted(A, key = lambda user: user['name'])
```

But how I can sort this list by a second value? Like `'age'` in this example.

I want a sorting like this (first sort by `'name'` and then sort by `'age'`):

```
andi - 23
john - 21
john - 22
john - 45
paul - 35
```

Thanks!

Comment: On a side not: python's sort is *guaranteed* to be stable, thus you could simply `sort` by `age` and then by `name` to obtain the result you wanted. (note that the keys are in reverse order. you first sort by the second key and then by the first).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
>>> A = [{'name':'john','age':45},
     {'name':'andi','age':23},
     {'name':'john','age':22},
     {'name':'paul','age':35},
     {'name':'john','age':21}]
>>> sorted(A, key = lambda user: (user['name'], user['age']))
[{'age': 23, 'name': 'andi'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 22, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 45, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 35, 'name': 'paul'}]
```

This sorts by a tuple of the two attributes, the following is equivalent and much faster/cleaner:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(A, key=itemgetter('name', 'age'))
[{'age': 23, 'name': 'andi'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 22, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 45, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 35, 'name': 'paul'}]
```

From the comments: @Bakuriu

> I bet there is not a big difference between the two, but `itemgetter` avoids a bit of overhead because it extracts the keys and make the `tuple` during a single opcode(`CALL_FUNCTION`), while calling the `lambda` will have to call the function, load the various constants(which are other bytecodes) finally call the subscript (`BINARY_SUBSCR`), build the `tuple` and return it... that's a lot more work for the interpreter.

To summarize: `itemgetter` keeps the execution fully on the `C` level, so it's as fast as possible.

Comment: I would be interested in an explanation *why* itemgetter would be much faster than the lambda expression. Doesn't it boil down to the same lookups?

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry I bet there is not a *big* difference between the two, but `itemgetter` avoids a bit of overhead because it extracts the keys and make the tuple during a single opcode(`CALL_FUNCTION`), while calling the lambda will have to call the function, load the various constants(which are other bytecodes) finally call the subscript (`BINARY_SUBSCR`), build the tuple and return it... that's a lot more work for the interpreter

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks, for the explanation. So the itemgetter implementation is optimized in cpython as c code, not just implemented as the reference python code mentioned in its online documentation.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry Yes. Note that the documentation says that it is *equivalent* to that python code, not that it is implemented that way. In particular `itemgetter` is really a `type` (see `type(operator.itemgetter)`) so it's not even a real function. This is typical: a lot of built-ins are implemented in C and often they are types and not functions(e.g. `enumerate`).

Comment: Hi @jamylak @Bakuriu:  Thanks for the solution provided. I like `itemgetter` and it does run faster. Just a question, I have quite  a few keys to sort. Is it possible to pass through a tuple or list, or any easier way by passing the variables instead of listing individual key names? I have a variable list, say `var_key_list = ['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5']`, any easier way to iterate, like loops or list comp for the values to pass within `itemgetter()`?

Comment: @XavierSun Do you mean something like `itemgetter(*var_key_list)`?

Comment: Hi @jamylak, I didn't realise we can use `*` to iterate the list elements to pass in `itermgetter()`. This is great. it is working well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 53):

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(your_list, key=itemgetter('name', 'age'))
```

Comment: Do you wonder whether `operator.itemgetter` does something nearly magic? It does not. It returns a tuple (of length two in this case) and then `sorted` does *The Right Thing* with that.

Comment: Good answer. But must be used like follows:

    your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list, key=itemgetter('name','age'))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative general solution - it sorts elements of dict by keys and values.
The advantage of it - no need to specify keys, and it would still work if some keys are missing in some of dictionaries.

```
def sort_key_func(item):
    """ helper function used to sort list of dicts

    :param item: dict
    :return: sorted list of tuples (k, v)
    """
    pairs = []
    for k, v in item.items():
        pairs.append((k, v))
    return sorted(pairs)
```