# Sorting list of dictionaries with list as values based on second item of list value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've a list which contains dictionaries and in each dictionaries the values are also list like :

```
a = [{"25.21" : [400,500] , "25.22" : [700,502]} , {"12.15" : [350,800] , "12.13" : [750,803]}]
```

I want to sort the main list according to the second item of the list which is the value of the dictionary which is again an item of the main list. The output should be like :

```
a = [ {"12.13" : [750,803] , "12.15" : [350,800] } , {"25.22" : [700,502], "25.21" : [400,500] }]
```

The first item of the list as values for each key inside dictionary would be different. How to do that in an oneliner if possible without using operator itemgetter?

This question is not same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082954/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-several-values). In that case, the values of the dictionary inside the list contained only integers where as this question has list as values of dictionaries inside the main list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to sort a list of dictionaries by several values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082954/python-how-to-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-several-values)

Comment: @BearBrown This question differs a little bit, as the values of the dictionary items in the list are also lists and the whole list is to be sorted based on the second item of the list values of dictionaries.

Comment: I don't think it's the same, there you order the dictionary based on a specific key, here the keys are not always the same.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It's a bit unclear. Show your effort and why it doesn't work. Idea: Create a function that extracts/creates the value you want to sort on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sorted`

**Demo:**

```
a = [{"25.21" : [400,500] , "25.22" : [700,502]} , {"12.15" : [350,800] , "12.13" : [750,803]}]

print(sorted(a, key=lambda x: list(x.items())[1][1], reverse=True))
#print(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.items()[1][1], reverse=True))   #python2
```

**Output:**

```
[{'12.15': [350, 800], '12.13': [750, 803]}, {'25.21': [400, 500], '25.22': [700, 502]}]
```

Comment: It's weird to sort using an arbitrary item in a dictionary. Is that really the intention?

Comment: This one still lacks a thing, that the each dictionary key value pairs aren't sorted inside the dictionary according to the second item of the list value.

Comment: So you also want to order the dictionaries based on the key value? That wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, the dictionaries also are to be sorted based on the second item of the value list. Like here in first dictionary 803 > 800, so key "12.13" would be first in stead of the key "12.15" as well as in the second dictionary 502 > 500 and so the key "25.22" would be the first in stead of the key "25.21".